# Añadir visualmente los puntos de decimales

Tags: html, css, chart.js

Me gustaría que al visualizar mi gráfica, los números que intervienen en ella tuvieran el formato `xxx.xxx`, ahora mismo los omite y no añade símbolo de puntuación ninguno.

He intentado añadirlo dentro de data pero no lo he conseguido que me cuadre.

¿Podríais ayudarme? Este es mi código, comenzando por script.js en javascript:

```
    const $grafica = document.querySelector("#grafica");
    const etiquetas = ["2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016","2017","2018","2019","2020","2021"]
    // Podemos tener varios conjuntos de datos. Comencemos con uno
    const andalucia = {
        label: "Andalucía",
        data: [149652,152310,156510,161084, 170061,191642,198983,212223,224142,234100], 
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(9, 129, 55,0.4)', // Color de fondo
        borderColor: 'rgba(9, 129, 55,1)', // Color del borde
        borderWidth: 2,// Ancho del borde
    };

    new Chart($grafica, {
        type: 'line',// Tipo de gráfica
        data: {
            labels: etiquetas,
            datasets: [
                andalucia, españa
            ]
        },
        options: {

            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: false
                    },

                    scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Superficie (ha)'
              }
                }],
            },
        }
    });
```

Y el html donde llamo a la distribución de chartjs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@latest/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="grafica"></canvas>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Y este es el resultado de mi gráfico:

[image: Salida de la gráfica]

Answer (score 2):

Salvo un pequeño error que tienes en la configuración de `yAxes` (te sobra unos `[ ]`), a mí se me visualiza con separadores de miles

Demo:

```js
const $grafica = document.querySelector("#grafica");
const etiquetas = ["2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016","2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021"]
// Podemos tener varios conjuntos de datos. Comencemos con uno
const andalucia = {
    label: "Andalucía",
    data: [149652,152310,156510,161084, 170061, 191642, 198983, 212223, 224142, 234100], 
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(9, 129, 55,0.4)', // Color de fondo
    borderColor: 'rgba(9, 129, 55,1)', // Color del borde
    borderWidth: 2,// Ancho del borde
};

new Chart($grafica, {
    type: 'line',// Tipo de gráfica
    data: {
        labels: etiquetas,
        datasets: [
            andalucia
        ]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: {  
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: false
                },
                scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Superficie (ha)'
          }
            },
        },
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:600px;height:400px">
   <canvas id="grafica"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias Yuseff, tu respuesta es correcta. Me he dado cuenta que la distro de la cual tiraba mi chartjs es diferente a la tuya y quizás el tipo de gráfica que he usado no llebaba puntuación.